# Chunks to symbols block, what is the use of 'dimension' parameter?

Tags: gnuradio

Can somebody explain me what is the use of 'dimension' parameter in **Chunks to Symbols** block in GNU Radio? As far as I understand it relates to dimensions in *symbol table* given as a first argument, am I right? Example with the practical use of dimension >1 would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out by analyzing the source code. Simply: for dimensions >1 one input sample is mapped to *dimension* output samples from the *symbol table*.
Example: input vector A =[0,1,2,3], symbol_table = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], dimensions = 2 you get output equal to: out = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] cause input sample 0 is mapped to 0 and 1, input sample 1 is mapped to 2 and 3, input sample 2 is mapped to 4 and 5 and so forth.